# How can I achieve a custom calendar in ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, calendar

Specifically, I want to achieve it embedded in a page,

[image]

And this is what I have could achieve using this calendar, https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar:

[image]

So, could I get what I want using the above calendar? Or do you have any better suggestion that I should use instead?

Comment: **mobiscroll** offers just the kind of features you are looking for at the modest sum of **$600** [that's the link to live demo](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/angular/eventcalendar/event-list-agenda#theme=material)

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if this is still useful, but I managed to change it by using CSS Content and using images. Just discover the name of the class you want to change and put the image above or under it, be sure tu make it absolute(and small) so it doesn´t expand your calendar cell.

```
  .monthview-selected::after {
   content:url(YOURIMAGEPATH);
   position: absolute;
  }
```

with this you can get results as follow
[Image-Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcUHA.png)